# Restrict webform component use to certain roles

Tags: entities, webforms

I want to restrict the usage of a custom component only to a specific role.
What's the drupal way of doing that?
I tried https://drupal.org/project/webform_component_roles but this just defines usage permission for all the components not each specific one.

Comment: Have you tried that module you linked in detail? The permission you mention allows an admin to assign permissions per individual field when you are editing the webform. Are you wanting to restrict people administering the form or people submitting the form?

Comment: People administrating. Yes I tried it. but I only show the single permission.

Comment: Sorry I thought you meant people submitting the form.

Answer (score 2):

Try Webform [Webform Locked Fields](https://drupal.org/project/webform_locked_fields) module, you can set permission for specific role

> Users who have the "administer webform locked fields" permission will
>   see a checkbox titled "Webform creator can modify" when they edit a
>   webform component. If that box is unchecked, the component can only be
>   modified or deleted by users who have the the "administer webform
>   locked fields" permission. Other users who have webform creation
>   permission will be taken to a page that says "Not allowed" if they
>   attempt to edit or delete that component.

Comment: This only restricts the instance of a component in a form. Ideally I'd like to restrict people from viewing the field if they are not allowed. Not even being able to add it.